# $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] in php reports different structure

Tags: php, ip, server-variables

$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] in php reports different structure IP's from time to time.

What I'm used to seeing was something like XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Now, I also have entries such as 
2601:100f:b13b:4bde:63df:a4a3:dc92:c416 etc.

What is this? & how can I learn more about it? Is this part of the IPv6 thing which has to do with the fact they are running out of ip4 Range?

Comment: Not that I care the down-vote, but I'm just curious as to what made the down-voter think this question is useless.

Comment: yes it's pv6 the client may be using ipv6.. i am not the downvoter most of server's changed to ipv6 as well as 4g phones

Answer (score 1):

This is an IP address on the IPv6 format, add you have suggested. You can read more about this here... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6